# ¿Por qué JCalendar me pinta el día de hoy en todos los meses?

Tags: java, calendar

```
class MyJcalendar extends JFrame{
    private JCalendar calendar;
    private JButton btnEnviar;

    public MyJcalendar() {
        setTitle("Ventana con Calendario");
        setBounds(350, 200, 400, 300);

        calendar = new JCalendar();
        calendar.setWeekOfYearVisible(false);//quitar nro. de semana del año
        calendar.setMinSelectableDate(new Date());//anteriores a hoy no seleccionables
        calendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(new FechasEspInv());

        btnEnviar=new JButton("Enviar");
        btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("fecha selec: "+calendar.getDate());
            }
        });
        JPanel lamina=new JPanel();
        lamina.add(calendar);
        lamina.add(btnEnviar);
        add(lamina);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static List<Calendar> fechasEspeciales(){
         List<Calendar> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

         Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 10);
         fechas.add(calendar);
         calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 10);
         fechas.add(calendar);
         calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 18);
         fechas.add(calendar);

         return fechas;
        }
    public static List<Calendar>  fechasInvalid(){
        List<Calendar> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.APRIL, 2);
        fechas.add(calendar);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
        fechas.add(calendar);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
        fechas.add(calendar);

        return fechas;
    }
    public static List<String> tipFechasEspecial() {
         List<String> tips = new ArrayList<>();

         tips.add("Septiembre 10");
         tips.add("Noviembre 10");
         tips.add("Noviembre 18");

         return tips;
    }
    public static List<String> tipFechasInvalid() {
         List<String> tips = new ArrayList<>();

         tips.add("Guerra de Malvinas");
         tips.add("Año nuevo");
         tips.add("Navidad");

         return tips;
    }
}
class FechasEspInv implements IDateEvaluator{
    int i;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    @Override
    public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
        calendar.setTime(date); 
        for (i=0; i < MyJcalendar.fechasEspeciales().size(); i++) {
              if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == MyJcalendar.fechasEspeciales().get(i).get(Calendar.MONTH)
                 && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == MyJcalendar.fechasEspeciales().get(i).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                 && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == MyJcalendar.fechasEspeciales().get(i).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
                     return true;
              }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
        return Color.GREEN;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
        return Color.WHITE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecialTooltip() {
        return MyJcalendar.tipFechasEspecial().get(i);
    }

    int j;
    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        calendar.setTime(date);

        for (j = 0; j < MyJcalendar.fechasInvalid().size(); j++) {
           if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)==MyJcalendar.fechasInvalid().get(j).get(Calendar.MONTH)
                  && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==MyJcalendar.fechasInvalid().get(j).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
        return Color.WHITE;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
        return Color.BLACK;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInvalidTooltip() {
        return MyJcalendar.tipFechasInvalid().get(j);
    }

}
```

Por ejemplo hoy es 12 de julio entonces me pinta ese día, eso está perfecto,  pero cuando paso al mes de agosto también me pinta el día 12 y así en todos los meses. Detecté que este problema hace que se confunda en la descripción del día, por ej. en noviembre me describe los días especiales 10 y 18 de forma correcta como le indiqué en el método `tipFechasEspecial()` pero el día 12 que es el que no debería pintar me lo describe como `"septiembre 10"` y así sucesivamente..en enero el 12 me lo describe como "noviembre 10".

Los `métodos` `isSpecial()` e `isInvalid()` sé que retornan bien por que esos pintan el día correcto y lo describen correctamente, el problema radica en que me pinta el número del día de hoy en todos los meces y además me lo describe tomando un valor de los días especiales como ser `"septiembre 10"`.

Seguramente se debe hacer de una forma más compleja que sobrepasa mis conocimientos, pero ojalá que se pueda así con este código sencillo para los que recién iniciamos, por que es muy útil y sencilla esta `librería`.

---

```
package pruebajcalendar;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;
import com.toedter.calendar.IDateEvaluator;

public class PruebaJcalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FramePrincipal frame=new FramePrincipal();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } 
}
class FramePrincipal extends JFrame{

    public FramePrincipal() {
        setTitle("Ventana con Calendario");
        setBounds(350, 200, 250, 200);
        JPanel lamina=new JPanel();
        JButton btnSelecFecha=new JButton("Seleccione fecha");
        btnSelecFecha.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new MyJcalendar();
            }
        });
        lamina.add(btnSelecFecha);
        add(lamina);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    class MyJcalendar extends JFrame{
        private JCalendar calendar;
        private JButton btnEnviar;

        public MyJcalendar() {
            setTitle("Calendario");
            setBounds(350, 200, 400, 300);

            calendar = new JCalendar();
            calendar.setWeekOfYearVisible(false);//quitar nro. de semana del año
            calendar.setMinSelectableDate(new Date());//anteriores a hoy no seleccionables
            CrearListasFechas crearListasFechas=new CrearListasFechas();
            calendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(new FechasEspInv(crearListasFechas));

            btnEnviar=new JButton("Enviar");
            btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("fecha selec: "+calendar.getDate());
                }
            });
            JPanel lamina=new JPanel();
            lamina.add(calendar);
            lamina.add(btnEnviar);
            add(lamina);
            setVisible(true);
        }

    }
    class CrearListasFechas{
        public List<Calendar> fechasEspeciales(){
             List<Calendar> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

             Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 10);
             fechas.add(calendar);
             calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 10);
             fechas.add(calendar);
             calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 18);
             fechas.add(calendar);

             return fechas;
            }
        public List<Calendar>  fechasInvalid(){
            List<Calendar> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.APRIL, 2);
            fechas.add(calendar);
            calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
            fechas.add(calendar);
            calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
            fechas.add(calendar);

            return fechas;
        }
        public List<String> tipFechasEspecial() {
             List<String> tips = new ArrayList<>();

             tips.add("Septiembre 10");
             tips.add("Noviembre 10");
             tips.add("Noviembre 18");

             return tips;
        }
        public List<String> tipFechasInvalid() {
             List<String> tips = new ArrayList<>();

             tips.add("Guerra de Malvinas");
             tips.add("Año nuevo");
             tips.add("Navidad");

             return tips;
        }
    }
    class FechasEspInv implements IDateEvaluator{

        CrearListasFechas objCLF;

        public FechasEspInv(CrearListasFechas objCLF) {
            this.objCLF=objCLF;
        }

        int i;
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        @Override
        public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
            calendar.setTime(date); 
            for (i=0; i < objCLF.fechasEspeciales().size(); i++) {
                  if (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) == objCLF.fechasEspeciales().get(i).get(Calendar.MONTH)
                     && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == objCLF.fechasEspeciales().get(i).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
                     && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == objCLF.fechasEspeciales().get(i).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) {
                         return true;
                  }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
            return Color.GREEN;
        }

        @Override
        public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
            return Color.WHITE;
        }

        @Override
        public String getSpecialTooltip() {
            return objCLF.tipFechasEspecial().get(i);
        }

        int j;
        @Override
        public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
            calendar.setTime(date);

            for (j = 0; j < objCLF.fechasInvalid().size(); j++) {
               if(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)==objCLF.fechasInvalid().get(j).get(Calendar.MONTH)
                      && calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)==objCLF.fechasInvalid().get(j).get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
            return Color.WHITE;
        }

        @Override
        public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
            return Color.BLACK;
        }

        @Override
        public String getInvalidTooltip() {
            return objCLF.tipFechasInvalid().get(j);
        }
    } 
}
```

Pero sigue el problema que mencioné al principio, describe algunos días como si fueran especiales y no lo son, los pinta bien, pero describe algunos de más, o sea cuando se pasa el mouse por encima.

Comment: ¿Sólo tienes esta clase? ¿Puedes agregar las importaciones necesarias?

Comment: Que al cambiar de mes se mantenga seleccionado el día parece el comportamiento por defecto de la librería.

Comment: Respondiendo al primer comentario, por ahora tengo solo esa clase que la ejecuto desde una clase con método main pero la idea  es usarla dentro de otra clase de mi programa. No entendí lo de las importaciones. En fin, la cuestión es como hacer para que no me describa ese día, ya que es el único error, después anda todo perfecto

Comment: Aprovecho para hacerte otra consulta: para usar esa clase, en realidad son dos(Myjcalendar y FechasEspInv), dentro de otra, no es posible ya que una clase tiene métodos estáticos y estos no están permitidos en clases internas, por lo tanto cuál sería la solución más conveniente?

Answer (score 0):

Ejemplo mínimo testable (refactorizado código pregunta, todas las clases están en el mismo fichero):

```
package CalendarRun;


import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import com.toedter.calendar.JCalendar;
import com.toedter.calendar.IDateEvaluator;
import java.util.List;

class MyCalendar extends JFrame
{
    private JCalendar calendar;
    private JButton btnEnviar;

    public MyCalendar()
    {
        setTitle("Ventana con Calendario");
        setBounds(350, 200, 400, 300);

        calendar = new JCalendar();
        calendar.setWeekOfYearVisible(false);//quitar nro. de semana del año
        calendar.setMinSelectableDate(new Date());//anteriores a hoy no seleccionables
        calendar.getDayChooser().addDateEvaluator(new FechasEspInv());

        btnEnviar = new JButton("Enviar");
        btnEnviar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("fecha selec: "+calendar.getDate());
            }
        });
        JPanel lamina = new JPanel();
        lamina.add(calendar);
        lamina.add(btnEnviar);
        add(lamina);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Fechas
{
    public static List<Calendar> especiales()
    {
        List<Calendar> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 10);
        fechas.add(calendar);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 10);
        fechas.add(calendar);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.NOVEMBER, 18);
        fechas.add(calendar);

        return fechas;
    }

    public static List<Calendar> invalid()
    {
        List<Calendar> fechas = new ArrayList<>();

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.APRIL, 2);
        fechas.add(calendar);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
        fechas.add(calendar);
        calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.DECEMBER, 25);
        fechas.add(calendar);

        return fechas;
    }

    public static List<String> tipEspecial()
    {
        List<String> tips = new ArrayList<>();

        tips.add("Septiembre 10");
        tips.add("Noviembre 10");
        tips.add("Noviembre 18");

        return tips;
    }

    public static List<String> tipInvalid()
    {
        List<String> tips = new ArrayList<>();

        tips.add("Guerra de Malvinas");
        tips.add("Año nuevo");
        tips.add("Navidad");

        return tips;
    }
}

class FechasEspInv implements IDateEvaluator
{
    int i, j;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    int month_day = Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
    int year_day  = Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR;
    int month     = Calendar.MONTH;

    @Override
    public boolean isSpecial(Date date) {
        calendar.setTime(date);
        for (i=0; i < Fechas.especiales().size(); i++) {
            Calendar fechaEspecial = Fechas.especiales().get(i);
            if (calendar.get(month) == fechaEspecial.get(month)
                && calendar.get(month_day) == fechaEspecial.get(month_day)
                && calendar.get(year_day) == fechaEspecial.get(year_day)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInvalid(Date date) {
        calendar.setTime(date);

        for (j = 0; j < Fechas.invalid().size(); j++) {
            Calendar fechaInvalid = Fechas.invalid().get(j);
            if(calendar.get(month)==fechaInvalid.get(month)
                && calendar.get(month_day)==fechaInvalid.get(month_day))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialForegroundColor() {
        return Color.GREEN;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getSpecialBackroundColor() {
        return Color.WHITE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecialTooltip() {
        return Fechas.tipEspecial().get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidForegroundColor() {
        return Color.WHITE;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getInvalidBackroundColor() {
        return Color.BLACK;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInvalidTooltip() {
        return Fechas.tipInvalid().get(j);
    }
}
```

Es necesaria la librería [jcalendar](https://toedter.com/jcalendar/)

Para ejecutar el código, en otro fichero:

```
package CalendarRun;

public class CalendarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MyCalendar myCalendar = new MyCalendar();
    }
}
```

Comment: El tema es que asi no me compila por que necesito tener todas las clases dentro de una clase de mi programa, o sea clases internas, y estas no pueden tener métodos estáticos. Pero ya lo resolví con métodos no estáticos, el inconveniente es que al ser así hay que crear el objeto cada vez que el usuario abre el calendario, y en mi caso por suerte no se usa mucho así que no sería un problema. Acá va el código para el que le interesa: